# Mongodb reusable aggregation lookup

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Is it possible to create mongodb reusable lookup, where I can use with every collection aggregation like createdBy with product, orders, etc. collections.

Comment: Do you use any programming language? In that case, you can keep the queries as an object/variable which you could reuse it.

Comment: I am sorry forgot to mention that. I am using nodejs with koajs. @Gibbs

Comment: You can keep that as a global variable. Isn't it?